# Make Android emulator stay on top Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, stayontop

How do I make my Android Emulator (from Android Studio) stay on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the three dots on the bottom of the side panel
2. Go to settings
3. Enable "Show window frame around device"
4. Now the standard ubuntu frame will appear at the top of the emulator. You can right-click on this and click on "Always on Top"